# Add coins to my existing coins

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've had a problem like this before with adding scores but never solved it so I figured I ask it now and have both problems fixed at the same time. I made an shop where people can buy coins that will be added to their coins they already have. The coins they already have can be loaded by:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *loadcoins = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedcoins"];
[coinsdisplay setText:loadstring];
```

and I have a button where you can buy 100 coins

```
-(IBAction)savecoins100:(id)sender { 
    NSString *savecoins = @"100"; 
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [defaults setObject:savecoins forKey:@"savedcoins"]; 
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

What I want is that the new string becomes not @"100" but 100 + previous coins now this would be loadcoins but I don't know how to code this correctly can someone help me out?

thanks

Comment: this question is a perfect example for the lack of the basic knowledge. :(

Comment: Hey he's trying at least. If you show code and have a specific question its better than a lot of others who aren't trying at all.

Comment: @RyanPoolos, I know, I'm just "killing" him. :) I'm always happy to help but one simple look at the **[NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)**... faster than typing a post here... for -4. :S the _Class reference_ is our Bible. :)

Comment: If prefer talking to people because like bryan he can explain me something like a teacher :) And you haven't killed me, try harder

Comment: Well as long as you're asking specific questions and trying with your own code first I'll be here to answer them. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for starters you should shouldn't be using strings... Why aren't you using an integer since you're counting?

```
- (void)addCoins:(int)coinsToAdd
{
    int currentCoins = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedcoins"];

    int newCoins = currentCoins + coinsToAdd;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newCoins forKey:@"savedCoins"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (int)getCoins
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"savedcoins"];
}
```

Then where ever you need to display it you can just create a string on the fly.

```
[coinsDisplay setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Coins: %i",[self getCoins]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
NSString *savecoins = @"100";
NSInteger coins = [savecoins integerValue];
coins += 78;
savecoins = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins];
```

and then you can work with the string again with the `@"178"`.

Comment: ...but I really like Ryan's answer as well.

Comment: Yea this is a good way if you're dying to continue using strings, Donny.

Comment: Alright thank you but if using strings is wrong then I will not use it anymore and use your way. So is it wrong or is it just different?

Comment: In programming the only thing thats wrong is what doesn't work. if it works its right. As far as best, I'd say you probably want to be using integers since thats what you're actually tracking is an integer instead of a string with the content of integers. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Alright If I do something I like to do it best, so I've used your code ryan it works good :) thank you I must say that I started coding out of nothing so there are base thinks that I just don't understand yet. My online multiplayer game is working tho

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `savecoins` to the `NSUserDefaults`. And `savecoins` is 100 so that makes sense that it becomes 100. You also say that `loadcoins` are the "old" coins. So you got two numbers here, `savecoins` and `loadcoins`. All you need to do is add them together. See Ryan's sample code.